# How to use Time format for hour greater than 24?

Tags: excel, excel-dates

I need the format `hh:mm:ss` into my cell, so I use : `Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`.

This is working fine when number of hours is lower than 24.

But for some cells, values are `35:58:00` or `46:12:00`. So, Excel replaced `35:58:00` by `01/01/1900  11:58:00` and `46:12:00` by `01/01/1900  22:12:00`.

There is a way to bypass this ? I try to use the format `"hh:mm:ss"` to do time calculations.

Thanks for help.

Comment: USe `[hh]:mm:ss`